# Build 2 Mirth Connect Channels

Tags: mirth

I'm totally new to Mirth Connect and Interface things.

The requirements are as beneath:

Build an HL7 ADT interface for updating patient location in RIS (Radiology Information System) whenever changes apply to patient hospitalization.

Interface Triggers: 1- Patient is newly admitted to ED
2- Patient is admitted to hospital
3- Patient is transferred from one unit to another
4- Patient is discharged from ED or hospital.

Mirth Channel: -    It is expected to receive the following information from a database with the above triggers from Patient table and the visit/transfer log table
o   Patient ID
o   Patient Triple Name (FName, MName, LName)
o   Patient Date of Birth
o   Patient Marital Status
o   Patient Age
o   Patient Full Address
o   Patient Phone
o   Current Bed
o   Current Unit
o   Current Admission Date
o   Previous Bed
o   Previous Unit
o   Visit Type (IN, ED, OUT)
o   Event Type
o   Event Date

- Analyze the three RIS Inbound ADT interfaces for commonalities.
  o   ADT A01 (Admit/Visit notification)
  o   ADT A02 (Transfer a patient)
  o   ADT A07 (Change inpatient to an outpatient)
- Build an interval-based channel that picks the admissions/transfers/discharge log and issue HL7 messages to RIS

Data Preparation:
    -   Build a dummy SQL Database that will simulate the real HIS DB 
    -   Build a structured table with the model referenced in 2.1.2 as minimum      set of columns. Note that you may need to add additional fields.

Mirth Channel RIS Simulator:
    -   Create a channel that listens to a specific port as to simulate the       Radiology Information System (RIS) 
-   The channel will respond with a successful acknowledgment no matter what
-   The acknowledgement message will contain the same “Message Control ID” received. Every HL7 message has a unique message ID

Mirth Channel ADT Interface:
    -   Create a channel that reads from the prepared data
-   It will be interval-based; for example, every 5 mins
-   It will read from the simulated database and filter records that were not sent yet
-   Choose two types of triggers to implement 
-   Based on the event type; formulate the respective HL7 message [Inbound guidelines are attached] 
-   Expect an acknowledgement message from RIS Simulator
-   Flag sent data when a successful acknowledgement is received so that it is not sent again next 5-min interval

Answer (score 0):

From you requirement I can understand one channel. (i.e Mirth Channel ADT Interface) I need more specificity on you other channel Mirth channel RIS simulator

I will roughly provide you a code base.

You will be creating a sql sample database. I have created MySQL db here.

[image]

Once you have created the DB, you need to configure the source in mirth as show in the picture below :

[image]

After this, you can create your specific code to HL7V2 in source transformer. use the following javascript code:

```
var uniqueControlID = UUIDGenerator.getUUID();
var date = DateUtil.getCurrentDate("YYYYMMdd");

//Field change on data
tmp['MSH']['MSH.7']['MSH.7.1'] = date;
tmp['MSH']['MSH.9']['MSH.9.1'] = "ADT";

if(msg['patientinfomation_eventtype']=="IN")
{
    tmp['MSH']['MSH.9']['MSH.9.2'] = "A01";
}
if(msg['patientinfomation_eventtype']=="ED")
{
    tmp['MSH']['MSH.9']['MSH.9.2'] = "A02";
}
if(msg['patientinfomation_eventtype']=="OUT")
{
    tmp['MSH']['MSH.9']['MSH.9.2'] = "A07";
}

tmp['MSH']['MSH.10']['MSH.10.1'] = uniqueControlID;
tmp['MSH']['MSH.11']['MSH.11.1'] = "T"; //note it can be either D,P,T,A,R,I
tmp['MSH']['MSH.12']['MSH.12.1'] = "2.4"; // Assuming we receive 2.4 version of HL7V2 message

//PID segment
tmp['PID']['PID.1']['PID.1.1'] = msg['patientinfomation_patientid'].toString();
tmp['PID']['PID.5']['PID.5.1'] = msg['patientfirstname'].toString();
tmp['PID']['PID.5']['PID.5.2'] = msg['patientlastname'].toString();
tmp['PID']['PID.5']['PID.5.3'] = msg['patientmiddlename'].toString()
tmp['PID']['PID.7']['PID.7.1'] = msg['patientinfomation_patientdob'].toString();
tmp['PID']['PID.13']['PID.13.1'] = msg['contactnumber'].toString();
tmp['PID']['PID.16']['PID.16.1'] = msg['maritalstatus'].toString();
```

Define a code template in the HL7 outbound transformer like this:

```
MSH|^~\&|||||||^|||
PID||||||||||||||||||||
EVN||||||||||||||||
```

When you deploy the channel you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

another method is to paste the below template in the outbound message template field and map the fields in the inbound message template with those in the oubound  message template

MSH|^~\&|AccMgr|1|||20050110045504||ADT^A01|599102|P|2.3||| 
EVN|A01|20050110045502||||| 
PID|1||10006579^^^1^MRN^1||DUCK^DONALD^D||19241010|M||1|111 DUCK ST^^FOWL^CA^999990000^^M|1|8885551212|8885551212|1|2||40007716^^^AccMgr^VN^1|123121234|||||||||||NO NK1